# program freezes after it has enumerated all subdomains

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, concurrent.futures

I am trying to create a threaded subdomain enumerator, and every time it's done enumerating subdomains on sites like google.com the program just freezes and doesn't exit so it doesn't print the final line `print("\\n\[+\] Done enumerating")`.

```
import requests
import validators
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def enumerate_subdomain(subdomain):
    http_url = f"http://{subdomain}.{domain}"
    https_url = f"https://{subdomain}.{domain}"
    try:
        if validators.url(https_url) == True:
            requests.get(https_url)
            print(f"[!] Subdomain found: {https_url}")
        else:
            requests.get(http_url)
            print(f"[!] Subdomain found: {http_url}")
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        pass

    domain = input("[+] Domain (e.g. example.com): ")
    file = input("[+] Path to wordlist file: ")
    threads = int(input("[+] Amount of threads (10-50 is recommended): "))

    with open(file, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        subdomains = content.splitlines()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:    
        executor.map(enumerate_subdomain, subdomains)     
        executor.shutdown(wait=False)

    print("\n[+] Done enumerating")
```

I tried adding the following line `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` after `executor.map` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hi, Please put your code all together in one code block as it's currently hard to read.

Comment: there it's already done, sorry i am new to stack overflow